# How to Debug PHP?? Sick of laravel white pages

Tags: php, laravel

These days I'm moving an old PHP project to Laravel framework and I'm struggling with these white pages that come up every hour. Back when I used Asp.net I never saw such a blank pages. But now in PHP and Laravel I always see white pages and I should solve the problem with guessing where the issue may be or not.
No matter what I do. "Display errors" is on. "Display startup errors" is on. Storage/laravel.log has nothing helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check APP_ENV to be local not production

read Laravel's Logging documentation

install a debugger extension: Xdebug is fine

if you are using feature tests consider adding 
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
to disable Laravel's exeption handling wich may lead to redirecting,...

if youre still unable to see error page it may be a php matter. check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display?rq=1)

[image: this is how a laravel err page looks like]

Answer (score 1):

Open the .env file in the root of your Laravel project and change `APP_DEBUG=false` to `APP_DEBUG=true`

Comment: It's true already